# Global Node Packages Installed to Wrong Directory

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, homebrew, hexo

I'm trying to install Hexo globally using npm. When I run
    `npm install -g hexo-cli`
I'm informed that it was installed to `/Users/myusername/.node/bin/hexo -> /Users/myusername/.node/lib/node_modules/hexo-cli/bin/hexo`

The problem comes in when I run `hexo init blog` and the hexo command is not found.

I installed Node and npm with Homebrew, so when I run `which node` and `which npm`, the results are `/usr/local/bin/node` and `/usr/local/bin/npm` respectively.

I'm thinking that I still have leftover files and directories from when I installed Node without homebrew, but I don't want to start deleting things without fully knowing the repercussions. Would I be safe to delete all files located in the `/Users/myusername/.node/` directory? I can't figure out why npm is not installing to the proper directory.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After a little digging, I found that my npm prefix variable was pointing do the wrong directory, left behind by the old Node installation. I ran `npm config get prefix` to see where it was pointing.

I set the new prefix value using `npm config set prefix /usr/local`. Homebrew is symlinked with this directory via `/usr/local/bin`. I uninstalled hexo-cli and reinstalled through npm, and now it works perfectly.

Comment: I was having a weird issue where things that would usually end up in `node_modules/bin` were ending up in my project root directory. A simple `npm config delete prefix` fixed this for me, thanks! (no idea where the prefix came from)

Answer (score 0):

**For NVM users**

Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v10.13.0 --silent` replacing `v10.13.0` with whatever version of node you're using.

Answer (score -2):

A simple way to cope with environment variables/path problems on Windows:

Run command:

```
npm install -g hexo
```

Using **node.js command prompt** rather than `cmd` windows provided by Windows itself.